Error after replacing ROOT.war in Magnolia
`I'm new to Magnolia and currently working on a project where no knowledge transfer has been provided, so I'm trying to figure everything out myself. I recently replaced the ROOT.war file in the usr/share/magnolia/webapps directory with a new WAR file (rpa-magnolia.war).
I attempted to deploy it using the following commands:
sudo service magnolia stop
sudo mv rpa-magnolia.war /usr/share/magnolia/webapps/ROOT.war
sudo service magnolia start
sudo tail -f /usr/share/magnolia/logs/catalina.out
However, I encountered the following error in the logs:
2024-11-05 07:01:39,250 INFO  info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader       : Initializing content repositories
2024-11-05 07:01:39,254 INFO  info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager : Loading JCR
2024-11-05 07:01:39,266 INFO  info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager : Loading JCR magnolia
2024-11-05 07:01:39,285 INFO  info.magnolia.jackrabbit.ProviderImpl             : Loading repository at /usr/local/lib/rpa/repositories/magnolia (config file: /usr/share/magnolia/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/config/repo-conf/jackrabbit-mysql.xml) - cluster id: "<unset>"
2024-11-05 07:01:39,618 ERROR org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl         : failed to start Repository: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1353)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createVersionManager(RepositoryImpl.java:486)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:311)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:589)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepository.createRepository(BindableRepository.java:141)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepository.init(BindableRepository.java:117)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepository.<init>(BindableRepository.java:106)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.BindableRepositoryFactory.getObjectInstance(BindableRepositoryFactory.java:52)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.RegistryHelper.registerRepository(RegistryHelper.java:74)
        at info.magnolia.jackrabbit.ProviderImpl.init(ProviderImpl.java:214)
        at info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.loadRepository(DefaultRepositoryManager.java:187)
        at info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.loadRepositories(DefaultRepositoryManager.java:173)
        at info.magnolia.repository.DefaultRepositoryManager.init(DefaultRepositoryManager.java:87)
        at info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ContentRepository.init(ContentRepository.java:143)
        at info.magnolia.cms.beans.config.ConfigLoader.load(ConfigLoader.java:141)
        at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener$1.doExec(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:253)
        at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext$VoidOp.exec(MgnlContext.java:443)
        at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext$VoidOp.exec(MgnlContext.java:440)
        at info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext.doInSystemContext(MgnlContext.java:403)
        at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.startServer(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:250)
        at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.contextInitialized(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:176)
        at info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener.contextInitialized(MagnoliaServletContextListener.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:480)
Caused by: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: JNDI name not found: java:comp/env/jdbc/MagnoliaDS
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getJndiDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:299)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.createDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:237)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:169)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.getDataSource(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:564)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.init(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:532)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager.init(MySqlPersistenceManager.java:51)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createPersistenceManager(RepositoryImpl.java:1349)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MagnoliaDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:850)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:850)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:161)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionFactory.getJndiDataSource(ConnectionFactory.java:284)
        ... 68 more

It seems to indicate an issue with the MySQL persistence manager.
Could anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how I might resolve it? Any guidance on how Magnolia works regarding the repository and persistence setup would also be greatly appreciated!`

Not really specific to Magnolia. Your datasource configuration expects to find DB connection at JNDI path java:comp/env/jdbc/MagnoliaDS and it's not there. Most likely because some environment variable that should be available to JVM is not set or has wrong value.
